# Iterate over files and exclude the ones with certain name pattern Shell

Tags: shell, posix

How to iterate over files in the current directory and exclude some files having specific name patters? The solution must be POSIX compatible.

Assume the files to exclude follow the patterns: test[0-9].txt and work-.* (using regex).

The code I have so far:

```
for file in * 
do 
    if test "$file" != "test[0-9].txt" -o "$file" != "work-.*"
    then 
        echo "$file"
    fi 
done
```

At the moment the output is all files in the working directory. I'm pretty sure pattern matching in test is incorrect, but how can I fix it?

Comment: could `test` do pattern matching?

Comment: @georgexsh I'm not sure, is there any other way to exclude files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[` is for bash, for POSIX shell, I guess [`case`](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) could do the glob style matching for you:

```
for file in *
do
    case $file in
        test[0-9].txt | work-*) ;;
        *) echo "$file";;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
if ! [[ "$file" =~ "test[0-9].txt" ]] -a ! [[ "$file" =~ "work-.*" ]]
```

Comment: It's saying `./test.sh: 11: ./test.sh: [[: not found` and still display unwanted files after this error line.